# Outputting UTF-8 encoded message with PHP die()

Tags: php, utf-8

I didn't think it would be so hard to find - but I seem unable to - a resource on how to output UTF-8 encoded message with PHP.  I am making a French language administration portal, and I want French die() messages.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's the problem? Make sure your document is written in UTF8, and that you're sending the appropriate content-type headers.

Your messages, should pull through just fine.

Comment: What other than my index file with the message, which is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, should I change?

Comment: @AndrewJackman: Try it and see. If it works, change nothing. If not, try adding `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8");`

Answer (score 2):

```
die('Le médecin est dans la maison'); //ta da?
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/are2xZeA

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// and/or
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and combine with **utf8_encode()** if necessary.